# It works different way, use <p> and <div> tag

Tags: jquery, html

```
$("#tt").hide();

<div id="tt">Some text. <div>Some text 2.</div></div>
```

It is OK, but this

```
$("p").hide();

<p>Some text. <div>Some text 2.</div></p>
```

hide only "Some text."

Could you help me understand why.

Comment: Do not nest DIV elements inside P elements! You are effectively putting a block level element into an inline element.

Comment: _"The P element represents a paragraph. It cannot contain block-level elements (including P itself)."_ -[w3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html#h-9.3.1)

Answer (score 6):

This is because nesting a `<div>` element inside `<p>` element is not valid HTML markup. So, the browser tries to fix it and modify the HTML to become like this:

```
<p>Some text</p> 
<div>Some text 2.</div>
```

That's why when you hide the `<p>` element, only "Some text" is hidden

Answer (score 0):

Your browser is closing the `<p>` right before the first `<div>` tag. DIV's are not to be nested within `p` tags.

Answer (score -1):

a `<p>` element may not contain other block elements like `<div>`.

try to use this [validator](http://validator.w3.org/)

and see this reference for [`<p>` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html#h-9.3.1)